# Codecademy "converting between symbols and strings" ruby lesson

Tags: ruby, string, symbols

These are Codecademy's instructions:

> We have an array of strings we'd like to later use as hash keys, but we'd rather they be symbols. Create a new array, symbols. Use `.each` to iterate over the strings array and convert each string to a symbol, adding those symbols to symbols.

This is the code I wrote (the `strings` array was provided):

```
strings = ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript", "Python", "Ruby"]
symbols = []
strings.each { |x| x.to_sym }
symbols.push(strings)
```

I know I'm probably doing multiple things wrong, but I've got through the ruby track this far with very little difficulty, so I'm not sure why this one is stumping me. Firstly, it's not converting the strings to symbols, and secondly, it's not pushing them to the symbols array.

Comment: The method you are looking for is `map`. `symbols = strings.map { |str| str.to_sym }`

Comment: @Rajendra_Prasad Do not use code formatting (backticks) for what isn't code. Code formatting is not for emphasis or to highlight technical terms.

Comment: Codeacademy is not accurate: you can not convert a string to a symbol with `to_sym`. What you can do is ( quoting the [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-to_sym)) return the Symbol corresponding to str, creating the symbol if it did not previously exist. The string is left untouched.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `to_sym` alone wasn't doing anything useful; it was converting the string, but not storing it anywhere or using it later. You want to keep adding to symbols array.

```
strings = ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript", "Python", "Ruby"]
symbols = []
strings.each { |s| symbols.push s.to_sym }
```

Or more elegantly, you can skip setting `symbols = []` and just use `map` to create it in one line:

```
symbols = strings.map { |s| s.to_sym }
```

`map` will walk through each item in the array and transform it into something else according to the map function. And for simple maps where you're just applying a function, you can take it a step further:

```
symbols = strings.map &:to_sym
```

(That's the same as `symbols = strings.map(&:to_sym)`, use whichever you find more tasteful.)

Comment: thank you. i'm going with your top answer, since i've not yet come across `map` in the lessons.

Comment: Thanks - check out the API, there's a lot of neat built-in functions like map. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html

Comment: 2nd example created a symbol array using `irb`, but CA did not. CA only allowed 1st example. another example would be `strings.each { |s| symbols.push s.intern }`

Answer (score 1):

`each` iterates over `strings`, apply the block to every element. However, it doesn't return anything. You'll want to add to the `symbols` array in the block itself:

```
strings.each { |x| symbols.push(x.to_sym) }
```

However, you can generate a symbols array in one line as well:

```
symbols = strings.map { |x| x.to_sym }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code to the following:

```
strings.each do |x|
x = x.to_sym
symbols.push(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strings = ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript", "Python", "Ruby"]

symbols = Array.new
strings.each do |x|
    symbols.push(x.to_sym)
end
```

This should be a exact answer..

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the new value as you iterate each value of the string, convert it to a symbol and then retun the value

```
strings = ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript", "Python", "Ruby"]
symbols = []
strings.each do |s|
  s = s.to_sym
  symbols.push(s)
end
```

Comment: My answer was based on exactly why the the code was not converting the strings to symbol and subsequently not pushing them to symbols arrary based on the codecademy instructions and example given to the learner at that point of the course.

Comment: @Matt kindly, bare in mind, the learner had not been introduced to  .map at this point of his/her learning track on Codecademy